# How to mockup a WCF service with a WSDL?

Tags: wcf

I have the WSDL of a very simple WCF service (regular wshttp binding), I plan to build and host a simple mockup service in IIS so that I can proceed with my development, is there any quick way/ helpful tool to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the service at all. Just use the interface and create mock service.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int a, int b);
}

public class MyMockCalculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```